# Starting Suricata with launchctl on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, security, launchd, launchctl, suricata

Using Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.3.

I'm trying to make Suricata start in daemon mode on boot with `launchctl`.
Here is my `/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.suricata.Suricata.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.suricata.Suricata</string>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/suricata</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>/usr/local/etc/suricata/suricata.yaml</string>
        <string>-i</string>
        <string>en2</string>
        <string>-D</string>
    </array>
<key>ServiceDescription</key>
<string>Suricata WiFi Net</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

But after launching

```
$ sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.suricata.Suricata.plist
```

Getting this in `suricata.log`:

```
[ERRCODE: SC_ERR_INITIALIZATION(45)] - pid file '/usr/local/var/run/suricata/suricata.pid' exists. Is Suricata already running? Aborting!
```

I tried to unload the daemon, delete this `suricata.pid` file, and kill the existing processes (which are actually not being killed with `launchctl unload` command) like this:

```
$ sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.suricata.Suricata.plist
$ sudo kill $(pidof suricata)
$ rm -f /usr/local/var/run/suricata/suricata.pid
```

But it didn't help so I've got this in `suricata.log`:

```
.pid' exists. Is Suricata already running? Aborting!
```

Please could anyone explain how to make suricata start at osx boot.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an answer:
Just in the .plist get rid of:

```
<key>KeepAlive</key>
<true/>
```

And now it's gonna kill all instances of the job when using `launchctl unload`